# value resolveOne is not a member of akka.actor.ActorSelection

Tags: scala, akka

I get the above error message from here:

```
implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(60 seconds)
val workerFuture = workerContext actorSelection(payload.classname) resolveOne()
val worker = Await.result(workerFuture, 10 seconds)
worker ask Landau(List("1", "2", "3"))
```

specifically from the second line.. the import made is

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.{ ask, pipe }
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
```

akka version is 2.2.1 and scala is 2.10.2, i'm using sbt 0.13 to build it all..
I cannot really understand what's wrong, since resolveOne is definetely coming from that package..

EDIT: I made a print of all the methods of the class with

```
ActorSelection.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).foreach { p => println(p)}
```

and this is the result:

```
apply
toScala
wait
wait
wait
equals
toString
hashCode
getClass
notify
notifyAll
```

Comment: `resolveOne` was added in akka version 2.2.1. Make sure that you are not using version 2.2.0

Comment: In sbt i'm building with scala-action v2.2.1..

Comment: You are printing the methods of the ActorSelection companion object, the ActorSelection class has always had a `tell` method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and changed my Scala and Akka versions as described in the link below.
I brought here part of my build.sbt for simplicity:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT")
```

link: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html